# VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04 blinking cursor what is the error

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I just can't get VirtualBox to work and i don't know what the error is.

When I press start I get a black screen with a blinking cursor. Virtualization is active in the BIOS. I have Windows 10 Home.

I followed every step of this video on YouTube, till the point he clicks start, then I got the blinking cursor: [How to Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on VirtualBox in Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5MhydijWmc)

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did that already. I followed everystep of this video, till the point he clicks start, then i got the blinking curosr : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5MhydijWmc

Comment: Put all that information [in your Question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1285161/edit), please, not buried in a comment.

Comment: If you are not locked onto Virtualbox (and even then it can help, but would need an extra step as shown in the doc) you might consider giving https://multipass.run/docs/installing-on-windows a try. By doing most of the steps for you it can be helpful to avoid some issues. If you want, IMHO worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try turning off Hyper-V? This did the trick for me on VirtualBox 6.1.

[image: screenshot]